# How can I use other fields validation to stop file uploading in Multer?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have added file upload to user registration API, it works fine but I have a problem.
I have added a validation for the email if the user enters an email that already exists in the database the API gives an error and refuses to insert the data into the database.
but I can't find a way to give the same functionality to the file and stop uploading it
the API :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const multer = require("multer");

// multer config
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./static/uploads/avatars");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("please upload only image");
  }
};
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: 1024 * 1024 * 20,
  fileFilter: fileFilter
}).single("avatar");

// Load User model
const User = require("../../models/User");

// @route   GET api/users/test
// @desc    Tests users route
// @access  Public
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Users Works" }));

// @route   GET api/users/register
// @desc    Register user
// @access  Public
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ avatar: "please upload picture" });
    }
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
      .then(user => {
        if (user) {
          return res.status(400).json({ email: "email already exist" });
        } else {
          // Everything went fine
          const newUser = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            avatar: req.file.path,
            password: req.body.password
          });

          bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              newUser.password = hash;
              newUser
                .save()
                .then(user => res.json(user))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            });
          });
          //
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem, I have added it to the fileFilter :

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // checking file type
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("please upload only image");
  }
  //check if the email is not exist
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      cb("this user already exist");
    }
  });

  // validation
  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  // Check Validation
  if (!isValid) {
    cb("is not valid");
  }
};
```